# How to redirect activity to fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments

whenever I open my app it open first fragment because it needed..what I am asking is..if user click on second item..the second fragment will appear and there i have text view named "second"..now after click on that text view,it will redirect to next activity..that activity has button,so when I click on that button,the fragment with text view "second" should appear..this is what I want..hope you get...

[image]

[image]

Comment: Well, a Fragment is usually **contained into an Activity** (exceptions: PreferenceFragment, DialogFragment). So, it's very unclear what are you asking.

Comment: ok..my fragment B is contained into mainactivity,then in my B i use intent and redirect it to another activity A,now i want to redirect from A to B...is it clear my brohter?

Comment: So you could use an intent to redirect from your Activity (where is the fragment ) to your activity A , no ?

Comment: You need study Docs for Activity and Fragment first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Fragment`s are inside an `Activity` you can switch between fragments like this

```
     getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
     .replace(R.id.content_frame,new YourFragment(),"fragment_tag")
    .addToBackStack(null)
      .commit();
```

If you want to go to specific a `Fragment` from other Activities (A is first activity and has a fragment like B and C is another Activity) you should pass `Bundle` to your `Activity`

```
//In C
Intent mIntent = new Intent(this, A.class);
Bundle extras = mIntent.getExtras();
extras.putString("Go_To_Fragment", "B");
```

Now get bundle in `A` and check if it's equals to B then replace  `B`

Another way is to add fragments to backstack then you can go to (only) previous `Fragment`s by pressing back button for example if you press back button in `C` you will come back to `B`(Assume that you call `C` from `B`)

**Edit1:**

I think you should use second way . Store all your fragments in a stack then your last fragment (like `B`) will store in the top of the stack .Now you can get the last fragment like this

```
getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
```

or

```
FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
int count = manager.getBackStackEntryCount();
if(count>0){
  Fragment  mfragment = manager.getBackStackEntryAt(count-1);
  FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
  ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, mFragment);
  ft.commit();
}
```

This will give you `B`